# Dropdown menu in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am just starting with ionic framework, trying to do an existing angular application to mobile as a hybrid app.

Is there any way to do a dropdown menu in ionic? I have searched the ionic website/forums and also googled but couldn't find any way.

Answer (score 5):

## Use [`$ionicPopover`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopover/)

It's a service included in the ionic framework that provides what you're looking for.

Here's an example from a project i worked on few months ago:

**[events-dropdown-view.html](https://github.com/Jossef/amigos/blob/master/www/src/events/events-dropdown-view.html)**

```
<ion-popover-view>
    <ion-content has-bouncing="true">
        <div class="list">
            <a class="item" ui-sref='create-event' ng-click="vm.popover.hide()" >
                New Event
            </a>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-popover-view>
```

[**events-view.html**](https://github.com/Jossef/amigos/blob/master/www/src/events/events-view.html#L9)

```
<button class="button button-icon" ng-click="vm.popover.show($event)"> <i class="icon ion-android-more-vertical"></i></button>
```

[**controller.js**](https://github.com/Jossef/amigos/blob/master/www/src/events/events-controller.js#L7)

```
app.controller("EventsController", function ($scope, $ionicPopover) {
    var vm = this;

    // Popover ( a.k.a dropdown )
    // ----------------------------------

    $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('src/events/events-dropdown-view.html', {
        scope: $scope
    }).then(function (popover) {
        vm.popover = popover;
    });

    // ----------------------------------

    // ...
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if this will help. This helped me at the same issue 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#select

```
<div class="list">


<label class="item item-input item-select">
    <div class="input-label">
      Lightsaber
    </div>
    <select>
      <option>Blue</option>
      <option selected>Green</option>
      <option>Red</option>
    </select>
  </label>

</div>
```